# UITableViewCell is not reuse properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I try to reuse UITableViewCell as follow:
1) Create subclass by UITableViewCell with xib-file.

```
@interface BaseCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;
@end
```

2) Add reuse identifier in IB
[image]

3) Add UIViewController with UITableView in it.

```
@interface BaseTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

4) in viewDidLoad register cell nib

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BaseCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BaseCell"];
```

5) and use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BaseCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BaseCell"];
    NSAssert(cell, @"cell registered but not created");
    DLog(@"cell:[%p]", cell);

    cell.labelTitle.text = self.showItems[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

After that I see that **cell created every time instead only first time**.
My log for example:

```
[0x7f87c9c84740:1] -[BaseCell initWithCoder:] BaseCell
[0x7f87c9c84740:1] -[BaseCell awakeFromNib] reuseIdentifier:BaseCell;
[0x7f87c9d3d230:1] -[BaseTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] cell:[0x7f87c9c84740]
[0x7f87c9e29560:1] -[BaseCell initWithCoder:] BaseCell
[0x7f87c9e29560:1] -[BaseCell awakeFromNib] reuseIdentifier:BaseCell;
[0x7f87c9d3d230:1] -[BaseTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] cell:[0x7f87c9e29560]
[0x7f87c9e2d150:1] -[BaseCell initWithCoder:] BaseCell
```

What I do wrong? **How properly reuse cells.**
I use latest Xcode (6.0.1) 
I created example [project](https://github.com/ins52/TestReuse) to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefits of cell reuse will only become apparent once cells go off-screen when scrolling (or become "unused" for some other reason - e.g. a reloadCells call).  The cell that disappears is put into the queue.  When the tableView next needs a cell, it uses the one on the queue, rather than constructing a new one from the NIB.

Comment: You are right. I forgot conception of reuse. It's work for reload but not create. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, the tableView will create and use as many individual cells as it needs to display at any time. Only when a cell is scrolled out of the visible area, it becomes available for reuse.